# Import maven project created in intellij to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying  to import a `maven` project from a project created in `IntelliJ IDEA`.The problem is that the folder structure is messed up and is not as per as maven structure. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have not same as [Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html),  you can setting up custom paths to source folders into your `pom.xml` as code below or fix it manually based on standard maven structure.
Seems like into `IntelliJ IDEA` project you have lot of custom configuration into `.idea` files

```
<sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>
<testResources>
  <testResource>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
  </testResource>
</testResources>
```